# I strucked while doing the problem Decode the string . why cant i use strr+=stack.pop() insted of strr = stack.pop() + strr

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def decodedString(self, s):
        stack = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i]!="]":
                stack.append(s[i])
            else:
                strr = "";
                while stack[-1]!="[":
                    strr=stack.pop()+strr
                stack.pop()
                    
                strr = "";
                while stack and stack[-1].isdigit():
                    strr=stack.pop()+strr
                stack.append(strr*int(k))
        return "".join(stack)
```

Comment: Could you please stop vandalizing your own question? After each of your edits the code is unreadable.

Comment: would not the results be different, in any case? += something would add at the end of sstr, but stack.pop() + strr adds at the beginning. Am I missing something?

Comment: Would you expect `strr = stack.pop() + strr` and `strr = strr + stack.pop()` to have the same result?

Comment: `X += Y` is the same as `X = X + Y`, not `X = Y + X`. String addition is not commutative.